# User Controls Importing Problem (asp.net)(vb)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, user-controls, import

I have this class that contains vars for db connection;

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Web.Configuration
Public Class DBVars
    Public Shared s As String
    Public Shared con As String = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("NMMUDevConnectionStr").ToString()
    Public Shared c As New SqlConnection(con)
    Public Shared x As New SqlCommand(s, c)
    Dim r As SqlDataReader
End Class
```

I import this to my page like this;

```
Imports DBVars
```

I'm then able to access these vars from my page.

But if I try to import them into a user control using the same method the variables are not available. Am I making an error or is this expected?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show the code which doesn't work along with the error message.

Comment: Is the class the above variables are contained in marked Friend? Shared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you're accessing them in your usercontrol like so:

```
Dim useMe As String = DbVars.con
```

and not something like

```
Dim x As DbVars = new DbVars()
dim useMe As String = x.con
```

You need to do this because you've declared them as Shared (static) and not as Instance variables.